# Getting custom colors and thresholds to work with D3 RelationshipGraph

Tags: d3.js

Based on this example: 
https://cdn.rawgit.com/hkelly93/d3-relationshipGraph/master/examples/index.html

D3 should allow me to create this chart and define colors and thresholds for when values change color. The function accepts some custom settings:

```
var graph = d3.select('#graph').relationshipGraph({
    maxChildCount: 10,
    valueKeyName: 'Story title',
    thresholds: [6, 8, 10],
    colors: ['red', 'yellow', 'green'],
    showTooltips: true
})
```

But I'm not getting a graph with three colors when I load data fitting into all 3 ranges. I want 0-6 to appear red, 7-8 to appear yellow, and 9-10 to appear green. Here's the data loaded (excerpt):

```
[
{"parent": "2012-October", "organization": "WEWASAFO", "value": 10, "Story title": "NUTRITION"},
{"parent": "2012-April", "organization": "Jitegemee", "value": 5, "Story title": "Life in the street"},
{"parent": "2011-May", "organization": "KENYA YOUTH BUSINESS TRUST (KYBT)", "value": 2, "Story title": "BUSINESS"}
]
```

Everything else parses correctly, except combining custom colors an custom thresholds on the same chart. Either one alone works, but not both together.

The source repo is here with some docs:
https://github.com/hkelly93/d3-relationshipgraph

From that documentation:

```
thresholds: [100, 200, 300], // The thresholds for the color changes. If the values are strings, the colors are determined by the value of the child being equal to the threshold. If the thresholds are numbers, the color is determined by the value being less than the threshold.
colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue'], // The custom color set to use for the child blocks. These can be color names, HEX values, or RGBA values.
```

It doesn't explicitly state that the child colors correspond to the order that the thresholds appear. And all blocks appear red in this example.

I tested the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/cgrx3e9m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in the module itself. I notified the author and he fixed the way it sorts thresholds so it matches up with corresponding colors now.

Comment: And he pushed the bug fix within minutes of my request! Amazing open source customer service!